# AngularJS Filter is not working as expected

Tags: html, angularjs

[image: Index page]

Right side Bajra atta, Besan, Corn Flour .. are subcategories.

**Index.html**

```
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'></div>


            <!-- Serach Area -->
            <div class='col-md-5'>
                <input style="margin-top:5px;" type="text" ng-model="SearchText" placeholder="Search for more than 10,000 products..." class='form-control' size="50">
            </div>  

            <div class='col-md-1'></div>

            <div class='col-md-2'>
                <a id="top_login" href="#Login" style="position:absolute; margin-top:15px; color:#FFFCBA"> 
                    <strong>LOGIN </strong>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">

        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-2 Name'>
                    <!-- Super Categories-->
                </div>


                <div class='col-md-7'> </div>

                <div class='col-md-2'>
                    <!--SC Cart-->
                </div>

                <div class='col-md-1'></div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <div id="middle" class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div id="left" class="col-md-2">
                    <!-- categoris and sub categories -->
                </div>


                <div id="right" class="col-md-6">
                    <div ng-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <!-- Footer --> 
    </div>

</body>
```

**products.html**

```
<div class='box' ng-repeat="product in ProductService.Products  | filter:SearchText | filter:FilterExpr:true| orderBy:'ProductName'">
    <!-- Display filtered Products -->
</div>
```

**ProductsController**

```
sampleApp.controller('ProductsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, ProductService) {

    $scope.SCId = $routeParams.SCId;

    $scope.ChangeFilter = function() {
        if ($routeParams.SCId)  {
            $scope.FilterExpr = {'SubCategoryID': $routeParams.SCId.toString()};
        }
    };

    $scope.ChangeFilter();

});
```

**config Code**

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Login', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/ShowLogin.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).
        when('/ShoppingCart', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/ShoppingCart.html',
            controller: 'ShoppingCartController'
        }).

        when('/Products/:SCId', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/Products.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/Products/38'
        });
}]);
```

When user clicks on subcategory, products of that subcategory is listed.
As otherwise is redirectTo: '/Products/38' products of subcategory 38 is listing initially.

I'm facing the following problems:

1. when user start typing in search box, filter:SerachText is applied on displayed subcategory products. **But at this moment i want filter:SerachText to be apply on all the products (Not only on selected subcategory products)**
2. Filter is not applying, if we are in some other routed page say login page. **I want as soon as user start typing in search Box products.html and productsController to be activate.**
3. When user has inputted something in search Box, and clicks on sub category, not all the products of that subcategory is listing because filter:SerachText is applied here. **In this case i dont want to apply filter:SerachText filter**

Can please some one help me to fix all these issues. I've tried all the combinations and permutations, but no luck. I'm also Ok if any architecture change is required that can make the things better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to hoist the `SearchText` filter scope to `$parent.SearchText`??

I guess, a superior scope (`$parent` or `$rootScope`) in your filter could work.

**BTW:** It works for me, 'cause it seems that ng-include does a local scope for each HTML to render, even in the same page.

P.D: Sorry for my English, greetings from Venezuela :D